# How to show PDF file from URL and show in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a recyleView which show list of client bills when clicking on bill I need to display the detail bill (bill Url - when pate the URL on browser its download as a PDF - required to authenticate) I used the below code to download the PDF, I can thee PDF is downloading my questions

a) how can I show this in webView

b) is there any other way I can show this PDF to the user without downloading/writing to external director

```
 if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

                        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            dm.enqueue(request);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "External storage permission required to save billing statements",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RESULT);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I show this in webView

`WebView` has no native ability to render PDFs. You can use Mozilla's `PDF.js` to render a PDF in `WebView`, though this only works on Android 4.4+ and requires some minor tweaks to `PDF.js` itself.

> is there any other way I can show this PDF to the user without downloading/writing to external director

You can download it to internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`), serve the file via `FileProvider`, and use `ACTION_VIEW` to allow the user to view the PDF using their preferred PDF viewer.

For limited PDFs on Android 5.0+, there is `PdfRenderer` in the Android SDK. `pdfium` is available for Android, but it is rather large. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html) for more about PDF viewing options.

There are also commercial PDF rendering libraries that you can research.

Comment: thanks for pointing to your blog post, if I understood correctly if webView can't render this PDF i can use Retrofit Client to download the file and use ActionView to show the file, no need of webView here

Comment: @Sam: Yes, you can use Retrofit and `ACTION_VIEW` to allow the user to view the PDF file. If you do not want the PDF on external storage, download it to internal storage and use `FileProvider` to get the `Uri` to use with `ACTION_VIEW`.